# Adding key/value pair fails with Object assign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that i am storing in local storage. I would like to retrieve the object and add an key/value item to it. This is the code

```
 var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

var newdata = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
var obj2 = {"four":"4"};
Object.assign(newdata, obj2);

$.each(JSON.parse(retrievedObject), function (index, value) {
  console.log(index+"  "+value);
});
```

The new item is not added to `testObject`. How can I add the item to the existing object?.

Comment: This is a simple error: you are mutating newdata, but then you start again from the JSON string and parse it again. Obviously the new property is not in that object, as it is not in the string representation. You would see the new property if you had done `$each(newdata, ... )`

Comment: can you point us to the line where you think you added the new item to testObject?

Comment: `$.each(newdata, function (index, value) {console.log(index+"  "+value);});` `newdata` is the json obj that contain the `obj2`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are successfully changing `newdata` but then you do not use it. Instead you are calling `JSON.parse(retrievedObject)` again.

```js
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
// Just use a variable because we cant use localstorage on snippet
var storage = JSON.stringify(testObject);

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = storage;

var newdata = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
var obj2 = {"four":"4"};
Object.assign(newdata, obj2);

$.each(newdata, function (index, value) {
  console.log(index+"  "+value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`retrievedObject` is a string. You parse the string, modify the resulting object (`newdata` gets modified). You should not expect the initial string to change.

In order to update localStorage, just do:

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(newdata));
```

Note that after that operation `retrievedObject` would still be the string with `{ 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 }`